# Fastest way to find locations from other numpy array(same shape) and calculate horizontal sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi let's say there are two numpy 2D arrays A, B with same shape.
I am trying to get elements from A where B element equals to x, and get horizontal sum of these elements at A.
I tried two following ways but they were both slow,,(it is big array)
Can somebody advice me faster way? Thank you.

First

`farr = np.stack([np.where(rarr == d, varr, 0).sum(axis=1) for d in digits])`

Second

```
@njit
def final_array(varr, rarr, digits):
  farr = np.zeros((len(varr), len(digits)))
  for i, d in enumerate(digits):
    farr[:,i] = np.where(rarr == d, varr, 0).sum(axis=1)
  return farr

farr = final_array(varr, rarr, digits)
```

Comment: It looks like your code attempts to do more than you described. How is `x` related to `digits`?

Comment: @DYZ digit looks like 'np.arange(15)' and all element of 'rarr' is one of 'np.arange(15)'